# Tor Path Selection using Stem to choose middle node

Tags: onion-routing, python, torsocks, stem

Has anyone had luck selecting the middle node used within the path selection of tor using Stem?  I am trying to set a specific set of routers (non public, so will have a different directory server, although I could set them to use whitelisting possibly) to be chosen as the center node in order to do some latency/throughput testing but the documentation is somewhat unclear.  I know one can select the entry or exit node using the torrc file, but it is impossible to select the middle node with this mechanism since it essentially ruins privacy to have it be chosen deterministically.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to construct the entire circuit yourself, you cannot just choose the middle node alone unfortunately. To do this, you need to use the `extend_circuit` command in Stem's controller API.